# Send mail in wamp using stunnel and fake sendmail

Tags: wamp

I have an error when sending mail.

> Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 k2sm10036004pdm.64

and the apache error log shows

> [Fri Mar 06 17:34:13.485200 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 2388:tid 736] [client 100.64.72.108:4978] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because I was editing the wrong php.ini. Check if you are editing this:

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini
```

And not this one:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini
```